# mysql table join with aggregates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 2 tables. `Person` table and `activity_log` table

There are many activities for each person.

I would like to "select" a list of "persons" showing the activity_name and activity_date of their last activity. (not all activities)

Person table has person_id, name, email

Activity table has person_id, activity_id, activity_date, activity_name

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery should do the trick:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.name, p.email, a.activity_id, a.activity_date, a.activity_name
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Activity a
ON p.person_id = a.person_id
WHERE a.activity_date = (SELECT MAX(a1.activity_date)
               FROM activity a1
               WHERE a.person_id = a1.person_id
               GROUP BY person_id) OR activity_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: This returns only 1 row and must still show employees with or with out activities

Comment: Let's try a `LEFT JOIN` here rather than an `INNER JOIN`. I'll edit.

Comment: still only returns 1 row with the highest date

Comment: Did some testing on my local box, give it a try now :-)

Comment: returning now multiple rows but all rows activity_date & date_time returns NULL

Comment: The query basically says, "Show me EVERYONE, and if that person has activities, give me the activity with the highest date, if they don't  have activities, just show nulls for the activity fields" Are you getting NULLs when there is an activity for that person?

Comment: Thank you very much. Works just the way i hoped it would.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your IDs are auto numbered, you'd do like this:

```
SELECT pe.person_id,
       pe.name,
       al.activity_name,
       al.activity_date
FROM   person pe
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT p.person_id,
                         Max(a.activity_id) activity_id
                  FROM   person p
                         LEFT JOIN activity_log a
                           ON ( p.person_id = a.person_id )
                  GROUP  BY p.person_id) AS LAST
         ON pe.person_id = LAST.person_id
       LEFT JOIN activity_log al
         ON LAST.activity_id = al.activity_id
```

However, users might enter past activities later than newer ones, then this will fail and you'd have to go like this:

```
SELECT LAST.person_id,
       LAST.name,
       LAST.activity_date,
       (SELECT activity_name
        FROM   activity_log al
        WHERE  al.person_id = LAST.person_id
               AND al.activity_date = LAST.activity_date) activity_name
FROM   (SELECT p.person_id,
               Max(p.name)          AS name,
               Max(a.activity_date) activity_date
        FROM   person p
               LEFT JOIN activity_log a
                 ON ( p.person_id = a.person_id )
        GROUP  BY p.person_id) AS LAST
```

But this still has a problem: since MySQL does not allow `LIMIT` in sub-queries, the query will fail if the same person has two activities with the same `activity_date` and that's the latest date.